# Postgres data source driver not found, but ODBC driver is installed

Tags: vba, postgresql, odbc

I'm hitting the below error on a particular server when attempting to insert data into existing Postgres tables from VBA:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I've done this previously on other servers, so I'm unsure what might be causing the issue. I've checked through a number of previous posts that are similar, though I believe I'm setting things up using the correct version of odbcad and I've tested the connection without issue. I've tried to provide links to the other posts, but it looks like I lack the required reputation.

I've set the System DSN up and tested it...which seems to be working. 
[image: ystem DSN]

I can also see that the 32-bit driver shows up under odbcad32:
[image: 32-bit driver]

Any thoughts about where I should look next?

Comment: Is your Office install 32-bit (assuming that's what you're using to run your VBA...) ?

Comment: Do you have the correct references set inside the VS editor? Dumb question b ut have to ask

Comment: what is the connection string you are using?

Comment: First screenshot is showing *System DSN* and second screenshot is showing *Driver*. You need to connect to the System DSN you created. As @JGH asks, please show connection string and attempt in VBA.